# Is it possible to make the git repo url shorter by any setting on private server

Tags: git, copssh

I config a private git server on win10 64bit system.
I used CopSSH service and putty client.
Now I can clone a repo successfully.

**HOWEVER**

The repo url looks like this

```
ssh://user@server:22/Program Files (x86)/ICW/home/hp/myapp.git
```

Since I use Copssh, I put things under `ICW/home` while `ICW` is under `Program Files (x86)`.
I want to the urls look and alsoI want to be able to put the repo in other place won't occupy too much disk of my `C:\`

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: 22 is the default port for SSH and you can omit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As show in [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/655560/Step-by-Step-Setup-Git-Server-on-Windows-with-Co), you don't have to install CopSSH in `Program Files`

> ### Install CopSSH
>
> a. Just like the msysgit, we don’t install the CopSSH in program files folder to avoid some space issues. We install it to c:\ICW

[image: http://www.jinweijie.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/image5.png]

That way, the url for any repo will be shorter.

Comment: It's right.So the best solution is to reinstall it in another place and possibly under a root directory?

Comment: and it may also follow with `ICW/home/hp`

Comment: @ShiheZhang yes, if you can reinstall it, that would be ideal.

Comment: Actually after I reinstall it raise another [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1195690/copssh-server-refusing-connection-connection-reset)

Answer (score 0):

On the client side,

```
git config --global -e
```

Add the following lines.

```
[url "ssh://user@server:22/Program Files (x86)/ICW/home/hp/myapp.git"]
        pushInsteadOf = ssh://myapp.git
[url "ssh://user@server:22/Program Files (x86)/ICW/home/hp/myapp.git"]
        insteadOf = ssh://myapp.git
```

When you clone the repo, just run `git clone ssh://myapp.git`. The push and fetch urls of `origin` will be `ssh://user@server:22/Program Files (x86)/ICW/home/hp/myapp.git` so the push and fetch will work as expected.

Other users with this config are able to use `ssh://myapp.git` as an alternative as long as they use the right `user` before `@server:22` in their own git-config. The `ssh://` could be `git://` or `http://`.

With the help of `insteadOf` and `pushInsteadOf`, you can assign one url to `origin` for push and another different url for fetch. If the two urls are the same, the `pushInstaedOf` part can be omitted.